# Reviews should show questions from your "favorite" tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, tag-watching

I looked at the "reviews" today for the first time on Stack Overflow.  It has a nice interface for quick action.  However, it's showing me questions with tags that I'm not involved with (not from my favorited tags).

It would be nice if it only presented me questions that have tags I've favorited.  (optionally?)

Or, better, could it weigh the review questions shown by the tags I've posted answers to.

Answer (score 5):

You can, to a limited extent, filter by tag already (up to 3):

[image]

I suspect that the system is already selecting the posts for you to peruse based on your activity, but I don't know whether it's exclusively using tags in which you've answered questions.

Answer (score 3):

In general, each review queue already prioritizes posts on which you have favorite tags, in addition to prioritizing more recently added posts.

I checked into your review activity, and saw that you were given a couple posts *without* your favorite tags from the **Close Votes** queue. The Close and Reopen queues are unique in that they focus mainly on prioritizing posts which have already amassed Close/DoNotClose/Reopen/LeaveClosed reviews. We made this change in an attempt to speed the Close Votes queue along, since it had been stagnating at ~60k for a while.

In other words, we are already prioritizing for favorite tags, but less so on the Close and Reopen review queues.

Comment: I don't think the different rules for close votes are a good idea. At least for me, seeing so many posts I didn't know anything about has put me completely off the close review queue on SO.