# On excessively large review queues, prefer posts with favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reviews should show questions from your “favorite” tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151627/reviews-should-show-questions-from-your-favorite-tags)

The close-votes queue on StackOverflow has about 50000 entries.

It will be helpful to get those entries out of this queue, that are within my area of experience. The area of experience can be determined by comparing the favoured tags of the reviewer with the questions.

Comment: You can already filter the review queues based on tags (click `filter` next to the queue's name)

Comment: @random, the filter-link is very well hidden. The software should prefer interesting posts automatically, just like the front page does.

Comment: Hendrik play around with the filter for a while and if you don't think it's enough, then by all means post a separate feature request for making the tag selection automatic (or, you could just edit this question and flag for mod attention, asking for the question to be re-opened).

Comment: @Yannis, I posted my comment after random added status-completed, but before he closed the question as duplicate. So I was not aware of the other discussion at this time.